# Numba, Numpy: Call @guvectorized function in a parallel @jit function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Consider the following simple function that calculates a similarity between boolean vectors.

```py
from numba import float64, boolean, prange, guvectorize
import numpy as np

@guvectorize([(boolean[:], boolean[:], float64[:])], '(n),(n)->()')
def tanimoto(fp_1, fp_2, res):
    bw_or = np.sum(np.bitwise_or(fp_1, fp_2))
    if bw_or != 0.0:
        res[0] = np.sum(np.bitwise_and(fp_1, fp_2)) / bw_or
    else:
        res[0] = 0.0
```

We can call this function with two boolean vectors but also (in good old numpy style) with one boolean vector and an array of boolean vectors to calculate the similarity of several vectors:

```
fp1 = np.array([True, False, False, True, False])
fp2 = np.array([False, False, False, True, False])
fp3 = np.array([True, False, True, True, False])

tanimoto(fp1, [fp2, fp3])
```

Now, I'm calculating the upper triangle of a similarity matrix which is basically all pairwise similarities of an array of boolean vectors.

```py
def similarityMatrix(fp_list: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    m = fp_list.shape[0]
    dm = np.zeros((m * (m - 1)) // 2)
    idx = [int((2*i*m-i*i-i)/2) for i in range(0, m)]
    for i in prange(0, m - 1):
        dm[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] = tanimoto(fp_list[i], fp_list[i+1:])
    return dm

similarityMatrix(np.array([fp1,fp2,fp3]))
```

However, it seems I'm unable to correctly @jit-compile and parallelize the `similarityMatrix` function. When I add the `@jit(parallel=True)` annotation, I get several of the following messages:

> Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "similarityMatrix" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'tanimoto': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numpy.ufunc'>

**Question:** Is there a way to make the inner prange-loop running in parallel? And are there additional things I'm not aware of to make this as fast as possible?

Sidenote: I'm aware of the scipy's `pdist` function. The goal here is to understand Numba better and get insight into what I'm currently missing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. In the Numba Gitter chat, someone pointed out:

> The issue is that guvectorize is generating a true NumPy ufunc instance, and it's not something that Numba can understand.

They proposed to try implementing the guvectorized function as a simple loop. Surprisingly, this indeed gives much better performance. The calculation of the similarity matrix for approx 7k values needs now only 13 seconds opposed to 1:19min with the vectorized version. The calculation calls the similarity measure  26,263,128 times and I'm quite happy with the performance.

The final implementation of the Tanimoto similarity matrix for boolean vectors now looks like this:

```py
@njit
def tanimotoSimilarity(fp: np.ndarray, fps: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    result = np.zeros(fps.shape[0])
    for i in prange(0, result.shape[0]):
        den = np.sum(np.bitwise_or(fp, fps[i]))
        if den != 0.0:
            result[i] = np.sum(np.bitwise_and(fp, fps[i])) / den
        else:
            result[i] = 0.0
    return result


@njit(parallel=True, cache=True)
def similarityMatrix(fp_list: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    m = fp_list.shape[0]
    sm = np.zeros((m * (m - 1)) // 2)
    idx = [int((2*i*m-i*i-i)/2) for i in range(0, m)]
    for i in prange(0, m - 1):
        sm[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] = tanimotoSimilarity(fp_list[i], fp_list[i + 1:])
    return sm
```